# What is the best way to create a CMS program

Tags: php, html, database, magento, cakephp

I've a project to create a CMS on PHP, without using Wordpress or joomla. The project will have an Admin panel and an user interface. Admin can insert products, categories,images and user can view the recent products and categories.
Right now I'm making the project on PHP and creating it from the scratch. Kindly tell me the best, secure and reliable way which is being used in the market to create such projects. I have heard about cakePHP, magentto and other frameworks. Which one will wok best or writing code in PHP from scratch will be the better option?

Thanks

Comment: BTW you can get started with yii with the help of this guide http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/ http://yii.larryullman.com/ these are the best tutorials on Yii I have seen by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/) is best with PHP and MySQL, you can create your CMS or any other category of project such as E-Commerce, Auction, Booking, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by checking these videos - **Building a CMS in CodeIgniter**. It will be faster and better than in pure PHP.

CodeIgniter is a PHP Framework:

- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZATIL9Rt7EU)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBMa34AwfB8)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmKrm3gQt9I)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udwYNtCmFmM)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCfm2SIQ5XI)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7F4PiyfwOtI)
- [How to build a CMS with Codeigniter : Part 7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3XxJDDeOOw)

Answer (score 2):

Smells like homework dude.

If its not then there are lots of other CMS' out there you can use that are free.

- http://www.concrete5.org/
- http://get-simple.info/
- http://grabaperch.com/

There are also a load of frameworks you can use to get you started, but until you write some code you won't get very good answers on here.

- http://symfony.com/
- http://fatfreeframework.com/home
- http://kohanaframework.org/
- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter
- http://framework.zend.com/

Comment: Actually i have started working on it from scratch using PHP, and getting lots of troubles in different areas. I have posted a lot of question in stackoverflow. You can check the code from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740737/unable-to-insert-multiple-images-in-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an existing CMS or framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) or [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/%E2%80%8E) to create the application. CodeIgniter is easier to learn and get going much faster thanks to its wonderful documentation. Its also convenient for a small project. On the other hand, Yii would take quite a while to learn it fully, but it offers a better approach to development if you understand it well.

In this case, I think CodeIgniter suits you more.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has two very good solutions for an e-store. [Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) is a well-established system that integrates with numerous payments and shipping systems. [Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) is the next-generation, which would require quite a bit of understanding Drupal to use properly. Writing the store from scratch is likely to be less secure and reliable because it's new.